# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

the following is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MedicineForm
from .models import Medicine

def index(request):
    all_medicine = Medicine.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'medicine/index.html', {'all_medicine': all_medicine})

def add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MedicineForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new = Medicine()
        new.name = form.cleaned_data['药品名称']
        new.price = form.cleaned_data['药品价格']
        new.number = form.cleaned_data['药品编号']
        new.sort = form.cleaned_data['药品分类']
        new.unit = form.cleaned_data['计价单位']
        new.save()
        return render(request, 'medicine/index.html')
else:
    form = MedicineForm()
return render(request, 'medicine/add.html', {'form': form},)
```

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class MedicineForm(forms.Form):
    药品编号 = forms.IntegerField()
    药品名称 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    药品价格 = forms.IntegerField()
    jj_choice = {
        '瓶': '瓶',
        '包': '包',
        '盒': '盒',
    }
    计价单位 = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=jj_choice
    )
    药品分类 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

---

add.html:

```
{% extends 'polls/index.html' %}


{% block medicine_form %}
<form action="http://localhost:8000/medicine/add/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="添加药品" />
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

---

traceback:

> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "F:\ddjj\x\mysite\medicine\views.py" in add
>     25.     return render(request, 'medicine/add.html', {'form': form},)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
>     68.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
>     66.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     208.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
>     174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
>     70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
>     961.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     1050.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_value_in_context
>     1028.     value = force_text(value)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
>     76.                     s = six.text_type(s)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in 
>     391.         klass.**str** = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in **str**
>     123.         return self.as_table()
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in as_table
>     271.             errors_on_separate_row=False)
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _html_output
>     226.                     'field': six.text_type(bf),
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in 
>     391.         klass.**str** = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in **str**
>     43.         return self.as_widget()
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in as_widget
>     101.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
>     537.         options = self.render_options([value])
>
> File "E:\p\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render_options
>     560.         for option_value, option_label in self.choices:
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /medicine/add/
>   Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 4):

```
jj_choice = {
    '瓶': '瓶',
    '包': '包',
    '盒': '盒',
}
```

should be written as,

```
jj_choice = (
    ('瓶', '瓶'),
    ('包', '包'),
    ('盒', '盒'),
)
```

key,text tuples.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
return render(request, 'medicine/add.html', {'form': form},)
```

you need

```
return render(request, 'medicine/add.html', {'form': form})
```

`,` at the end makes it tuple