# Django ValueError - not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: django

Getting the error in the title when I try to go on my `listing_public` page, can't figure out why.

**views.py**

```
def listing_public(request, pk):

    listing = get_object_or_404(BuyerListing, pk)

    return render (
        request,
        'listing_public.html',
        context={'listing':listing}
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^listing/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.listing_public, name='listing_public'),
```

**Template Tags**

```
{% url 'listing_public' pk=listing.pk %}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732496/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-2-got-1) is the only other question on Stack Overflow I found regarding this error, but the sole answer didn't solve my problem.  Here is the [traceback](http://dpaste.com/2GW3Y9W).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See if specifying the argument changes anything

```
listing = get_object_or_404(BuyerListing, pk=pk)
```